# Enabling a bridged NIC in WMWare fails because of pending update

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, bridge

I run a virtual machine under VMWare Workstation 10.0.1 build-1379776, on a Windows 7 Pro 64 bits desktop. The virtual machine having problems is an Endian firewall community edition 2.5.2, although I don't think it is related.

There are two adapters on the VM : one is "host only" and it works. Virtual machines behind the firewall are networked toghether just fine.

The second adapter is bridged to a physical wired NIC, VMnet0. For some reason, the network adapter is not "Connected". VM behind the firewall can't connect to the internet and I can't connect to the VM, other than using the VMWare console.

[image: VMWare bridged adapter is not connected]

But when I check the "Connected" box and click OK, I get a message saying "**Failed to complete requested operation while ethernet1 has a operation pending**". In the Endian VM, ethernet1 is the bridged NIC.

[image: Failed to complete requested operation while ethernet1 has a operation pending]

What *operation* could be pending (how can I debug this) ?

Comment: Have you installed any software that requires a reboot to install properly ?

Comment: Not that I know. I've rebooted several times and Windows update shows nothing, not even an optional update. I use that desktop as a server. I never "work" on it. It hosts the virtual machines that I connect to for work/play.